# Using a Synapse Notebook, how to use the exit value in calling an api?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am new to this and tried many hours in looking this up but to no avail. I am using a notebook because it is easier to modify a set of values. The notebook accepts a list of values, inserts special characters in between the values and then exit that overall value to the pipeline. How do I then use this value in a relative url in an API call?

So far I have this.[image: img].

I exited the value from the note book using this "mssparkutils.notebook.exit(concatoutput)"

I then used Set Variable [image: img] with the value being "@activity('csvtostring').output.status.Output.result.exitValue"

And I am using this to call my API
[image: img].

Comment: Are you getting any error in this approach?

Comment: Don't know to call the API, so I am stuck here.

Comment: In this [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny7CC.png) , you are using the API. Are you trying to copy the data from api to any other datasource?

Comment: Hi there, Yes I am. A special code is produced by the notebook where I want to use it in the relative URL to call that. However I do not know how to exit that value from my notebook and place it in the relative URL.

Comment: `@activity('csvtostring').output.status.Output.result.exitValue` --  Did the value from notebokk activity get assigned to variable correctly? Could you share the csvtostring activity's output json response from adf.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on **open** in the source dataset of copy activity.
  [image]
- In Source dataset, click the parameters tab and then create a new parameter `RelativeURL` of string type.
  [image]
- Then click connection tab in source dataset and give the Relative URL value `@dataset().RelativeURL` as a dynamic content.
  [image]
- Then again in source settings of copy activity, under dataset properties, give the value for parameter as `@variables('IDBatchString)`

[image]

This is the way to pass the relative url value dynamically from notebook activity to source dataset of copy activity.